# Why is androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders in "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions" instead of "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel"?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components

I create a default project in Android Studio 3.6. I could have access to `ViewModel()` as below without add any library to my build.gradle

```
class MyViewModel() : ViewModel()
```

It will `import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel`

I'm surprise, as I didn't even have `"android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel"` in my gradle.

However, when I want to use `ViewModelProviders`, as below

```
private val viewModel: MyViewModel by lazy {
    ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
}
```

I'm surprise it is not readily available, nor is it in `"android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel"` library. 
Instead it is in the `"android.arch.lifecycle:extensions"` library, that I have explicitly add.

Why is `ViewModelProviders` in `lifecycle:extensions` instead of `lifecycle:viewmodel` library? I thought it's the essential part of having a `ViewModelProviders` when we use `ViewModel()`?

Additional question: When do we need to include `"android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel"`, since `ViewModel()` seems to be available by default?

Comment: "I'm surprise it is not readily available, nor is it in "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel" library. Instead it is in the "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions" library, that I have explicitly add." -- it is in neither of those. Jetifier is swapping in the proper artifact for you, apparently. No `androidx` classes are in the legacy `android.arch` artifacts. `ViewModelProviders` [is in `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions`](https://androidx.tech/packages/androidx.lifecycle#ViewModelProviders).

Comment: "When do we need to include "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel", since ViewModel() seems to be available by default?" -- it is not available by default. You are getting `ViewModel` from a transitive dependency from some other artifact that you are including.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare. As I only open up the default project, the only library included is ` implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'` Does that mean from it, we could get the `ViewModel` transitively?

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare, I don't understand the statement ` it is in neither of those` and follow by `ViewModelProviders is in androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions`. The two are contradicting each other. I may have miss understood you?

Comment: "Does that mean from it, we could get the ViewModel transitively?" -- yes. You can see that artifact version's transitive dependencies [here](https://androidx.tech/artifacts/appcompat/appcompat/1.1.0). One of those is to `androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0`, and [*it's* transitive dependencies](https://androidx.tech/artifacts/fragment/fragment/1.1.0) includes `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0`.

Comment: "I may have miss understood you?" -- your question refers to `android.arch` artifacts, not `androidx` ones.